# HINSTANCE member of WNDCLASSEX ignored on call to RegisterClassEX?

Tags: windows, winapi

Does RegisterClassEx()  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx) simply ignore the value specified in the HINSTANCE member of a WNDCLASSEX structure when registering a window class?

```
ATOM one = registerClass((HINSTANCE)1, (WNDPROC)0);
ATOM two = registerClass((HINSTANCE)2, (WNDPROC)0);
return 0;

ATOM registerClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC wndProc){

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = wndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance; 
    wcex.hIcon          = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL; //MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_FRAMEWORK);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = TEXT("Fag");
    wcex.hIconSm        = NULL;
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

In the above code the second call to registerClass() results in an error, with the error code being that the class is already registered i.e. in the first call.

But the values passed for HINSTANCE in both cases different, suggesting that they are ignored.

Can anyone confirm that it is ignored?

Comment: 1 and 2 are not valid instance handles. You are therefore invoking undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can result in anything. Returning strange errors counts as "anything".

Comment: The hInstance member is supposed to identify the module that contains the window procedure, so even if RegisterClassEx is not using this value, I'm pretty sure that Windows will use this value when it wants to send messages to the window procedure.

Comment: You are trying to register the two classes with the same name, so I'm not surprised the second call fails.

Comment: Update: The code was code in an exe intended to simulate the registration of a class by a dll and by an exe with the same name. The 1 was to represent the HINSTANCE of the exe file. The 2 to represent the HMODULE of the dll. I worked out how to make dll's and utilised valid values in my code. Once I did that the code worked as I wanted, and was attempting to simulate. I had read the entry on Raymond's blog regarding HINSTANCE and it's use in calls to RegisterWindow and CreateWindow. I didn't think the system would particularly care about whether the values were valid or invalid.

Comment: Oh, I understand now (sort of). This MSDN article might be helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Especially the section on Application Local Classes and the section on the instance handle. Of course, the classes that you are registering are Application Local classes (because you didn't use CS_GLOBALCLASS as a class style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RegisterClassEx function does not simply ignore the value specified in the hInstance member of a WNDCLASSEX structure. The RegisterClassEx function does however return unexpected results if it is passed an invalid value in the hInstance member of a WNDCLASSEX structure.